# Odoo, how to override an action extending it's domain (not overriding)

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-12

In a module that I do NOT own is the following act_window.

```
<record id="act_465" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Act 465</field>
    <field name="res_model">stock.move</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="domain">[('available','=',True)]</field>
</record>
```

I would like to add the following AND criteria to the domain in my separate module:

```
('canceled', '!=', True)
```

I know I could **OVERRIDE** the act_window and the value of domain by `[('available','=',True),('canceled', '!=', True)]`. However doing so would totally remove what was already in place `('available','=',True)`. Meaning that if the owner of the base module change it's domain, I'll override his changes anyway.

**Question**

How could I **EXTEND** the domain by saying "I would like to add `('available','=',True)` to the existing domain" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, the action domain is a char field and there is no attribute to specify how to extend a specific record value.

It is possible to use the [function](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/data.html#function) tag in the XML data file to call the write method and update the domain or create a function to update the action domain with a given domain list as a parameter.

- Use the function tag to update the domain as a string (we suppose that the domain is set, list of tuples provided as a string)

  ***Example:***

  ```
  <function model="ir.actions.act_window" name="write">
      <value eval="[ref('sale.action_quotations_with_onboarding')]"/>
      <value model="ir.actions.act_window" eval="{'domain':  obj().env['ir.actions.act_window'].browse(ref('sale.action_quotations_with_onboarding')).domain[:-1] + ', (\'invoice_status\', \'=\', \'to invoice\')]'}"/>
  </function>
  ```

- Create a function to update the domain as a list with a given domain as a parameter

  ***Example:***

  ```py
  class IrActionsActWindow(models.Model):
      _inherit = 'ir.actions.act_window'

      def update_domain(self, new_domain=None):
          if new_domain:
              self.write({'domain': safe_eval(self.domain) + new_domain})
  ```

  Use the function to call the `update_domain` method:

  ```xml
  <function model="ir.actions.act_window"
            name="update_domain"
            eval="[ref('sale.action_quotations_with_onboarding'), [('invoice_status', '=', 'to invoice')]]"/>
  ```